# can anyone suggest a good light weight rails CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

here are the requirement from marketing people:
1. they want to be able to setup google adwords and being able to create a landing page, select a template layout, and able to fill in matching title and description. Unique, readable URL is important as well.
2. they want to be able to modify static pages on the site, e.g. about us, FAQs, they want to be able to change the copies, and pictures. not the layout

I am thinking just use RedCloth, allowing them to write HTML themselves, and save the copy into a 'TextResource' model. Simple as that. But i also want to know if there are other better options

thanks

Comment: thanks, but looks like all suggested cm systems require their own databases, admins panels, etc, is there anything can be used as a plugin, with existing project database and admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/)? I think it fits your criteria and it is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 I know of that standout and should meet your needs.

- [Radiant CMS](http://github.com/radiant/radiant)
- [Refinery CMS](http://github.com/resolve/refinerycms)

Answer (score 1):

Try SkylineCMS: http://www.skylinecms.nl
It does all the things you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the difference between Radiant and Refinery, you may check out my post http://www.shanison.com/2011/03/29/radiant-cms-vs-refinery-cms/ As it can't be said in one sentence here.